# Questions about matrices and determinants - constant variable multiplication

Tags: matrices, determinant

Is this matrix
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
       a & -a & a           \\[0.3em]
       -a & -a & -a         \\[0.3em]
       a & a & a
     \end{bmatrix}
$$
the same as:
$$
M = a\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & -1 & 1           \\[0.3em]
       -1 & -1 & -1         \\[0.3em]
       1 & 1 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}
$$
or
$$
M = a^3\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & -1 & 1           \\[0.3em]
       -1 & -1 & -1         \\[0.3em]
       1 & 1 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}
$$
?
what about determinants:
$$
det \begin{bmatrix}
       a & -a & a           \\[0.3em]
       -a & -a & -a         \\[0.3em]
       a & a & a
     \end{bmatrix}
$$
is it the same as:
$$
a*det \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & -1 & 1           \\[0.3em]
       -1 & -1 & -1         \\[0.3em]
       1 & 1 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}
$$
or
$$
a^3*det\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & -1 & 1           \\[0.3em]
       -1 & -1 & -1         \\[0.3em]
       1 & 1 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}
$$
?

Comment: for matrix $a$ is correct and determinant $a^3$ is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & -a & a \\ -a & -a & -a \\ a & a & a\end{pmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{vmatrix} a & -a & a \\ -a & -a & -a \\ a & a & a\end{vmatrix} = a^3\begin{vmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{vmatrix}$$ although in this specific case all determinants are in fact equal since they are all zero.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can understand better the relation between determinants by observing that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & -a & a \\
-a & -a & -a \\
a & a & a
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & a & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a
\end{bmatrix}\,
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

By definition, $aM$ means multiplying all entries of $M$ by $a$.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, the determinat, seen as a function of the columns, is multilinear, i.e. let $A_1, \dots, A_n$ be the columns of the matrix $A$, then $\text{det}(A) = D(A_1, \dots, A_n)$, and $$D(A_1, \dots , \lambda A_i+\mu B,\dots, A_n) = \lambda \det(A) + \mu \det (M),$$ where $M$ is the matrix whose columns are $A_1, \dots, B, \dots, A_n$.